# C++ Lambda stored in container capturing "this"

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Consider the following minimal code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
  A() :
    s("dummy"),
    f([&, this]{ return s == "dummy"; }),
  {}
  std::string s;
  std::function<bool ()> f;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  A a;
  a.f(); // seems fine

  std::vector<A> as({});
  as[0].f(); // segmentation fault
}
```

Class `A` has a lambda member that captures `this` pointer. When running the code above, lambda works fine when invoked from standalone `A` instance, but I get segmentation fault when called from an instance stored in the vector.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Because the `f` member isn't copyable, and you're violating the vector's preconditions.

Comment: Forgot the say I'm using clang-700.1.81 with -std=c++14 compilation option.

Comment: What do you think `as({})` is doing? Try printing the size of the vector after that statement.

Comment: @Praetorian That said, even with that fixed, the code is still broken...

Comment: @ Kerrek SB. According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function, std::function is CopyConstructible. Still, f isn't copyable?

Comment: @Praetorian You should post an answer, this is a good question IMO, why is it downvoted? I'm pretty sure there are lots of C++ programmers around that have no idea why this is UB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of different problems with your example. This line

```
std::vector<A> as({});
```

constructs an empty `vector`. When you index into the first element on the next line, you have undefined behavior, and your program crashes in this case.

If you change that to

```
std::vector<A> as;
as.emplace_back();
a[0].f();
```

the code will work as you expect, but that doesn't mean there are no more problems. If you add a few more elements to your `vector`, it'll reallocate storage to accommodate the new elements, and the previously stored lambdas will get move constructed. But when that happens, they will still retain their old `this` pointer values, which point to objects that are now dead. Invoking the lambda after that is undefined behavior.

Here's an example of the potential problems

```
class A
{
public:
  A() :
    s("dummy"),
    f([&, this]{ std::cout << this << '\n'; return s == "dummy"; })
  {}
  std::string s;
  std::function<bool ()> f;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<A> as;
  {
    A a;
    a.f();
    as.push_back(a);  // make a copy of a
    as[0].f();        // this pointer stays the same as the original
  } // lifetime of a ends

  as[0].f();  // undefined behavior
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67afaf6d0324302a)

Comment: You are right, the problem here was the vector initialization. If I use `std::vector<A> as({{}});` (instead of single curly bracket), works as expected. Thanks.

Comment: @Spagnol No, it doesn't work. Try to understand what I said in the answer, you have bigger problems with the lambda than additional empty braces can solve. Writing `std::vector<A> as({{}});` means the element you added to the vector was copy constructed from the element in the initializer list, and all the `this` pointer problems described above exist. See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee7c35d04839d2a3); notice that the `this` pointer printed in the lambda matches that of the element in the intializer list, and it is printed after that object was destroyed.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer last night. Now I see the `this` is captured when the lamba is constructed, and when the lambda is copied into the container, it brings the original `this` along. The solution might be passing `this` as a lamba parameter instead of a capture. I appreciate your help.